# Show that $(V \times V)/\bigtriangleup \cong V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a vector space. Let $\bigtriangleup$ be the diagonal of $V \times V$ of the form $(x,x) \in V \times V$, $x \in V$.

Trying to show that $(V \times V)/\bigtriangleup \cong V$

Consider the mapping $T: V \times V \rightarrow V$ by $T(x,y) = x-y$, then the kernel of $T$ is $\bigtriangleup$. I am having difficulty with the injectivity of a mapping $f:(V \times V)/\bigtriangleup \rightarrow V$

Comment: Apply the isomorphism theorem on $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map $T: V \times V \to V$ given by $T((x,y)) = x-y$. Note that: $(x,y) \in \ker(T) \iff T((x,y)) =0 \iff x-y=0 \iff x=y \iff (x,y) \in \Delta$.

Hence $\Delta = ker(T)$.

To show that $V$ is indeed the range of $T$, let $v \in V$. Note that for the element $(2v,v) \in V \times V$, $T((2v,v)) = 2v-v=v$. Hence $T$ is surjective on $V$.

Now the first isomorphism theorem says that for any linear transformation $T:X \to Y$,

> $\dfrac{X}{\ker(T)} \cong \text{range}(T)$

Hence, it follows that $\dfrac{V \times V}{\Delta} \cong V$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the first isomorphism theorem for vector spaces. You've shown the kernel is $\Delta$. You are just left to show that $T$ is linear and surjective (if it is) then $(V \times V)/\Delta \cong T(V \times V) = V$.